# Video won't load when page first loads

Tags: html, performance, video, download, load

When I load the website it does not load the video but if I press the logo and load the index.html file again it loads the video fine?

My html is

```html
 <video width="100%" height="500px" autoplay loop >
     <source src="/Website Banner.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
 </video>
```

The site is [nsnf.williammarks.co.uk](http://nsnf.williammarks.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

Your src is missing something... a "/"...
Also try to only use lowercases as files titles.

```
<video width="100%" height="500px" autoplay loop>
<source src="/website/banner.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

gl.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. Maybe do this:

1 - Add an id to the video element:

```
<video id="myVid" width="100%" height="500px" autoplay loop >
    <source src="/Website Banner.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

2 - Add a script at the end:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("myVid").play()
</script>
```